# Jasper Reports Adhoc View empty

Tags: jasperserver

I hope this is not too much to ask.

Can someone help me or provide me with a reference applicationContext-multiTenancy-security.xml from a commercial license JasperSoft server that has been setup against external users from a third party web application that are not in LDAP and with which the users can see the topics and domains in the user interface in Jasper Reports server UI?

The problem is that I have users coming from a web application authenticated fine through acegi into the JasperSoft application and as a superuser I created a domain as well as topic successfully using the Add Resource options. I have put the topic in /adhoc/topics and the domain in /public/domains, however I get nothing shown in the View Ad hoc Reports view (dataExplorer.jsp is suppose to show trees).

Answer (score 0):

I took out defer from a script tag in the line

```
<script defer src="adhoc/scripts/adHocDeferred.js"></script>
```

and then the trees show up.

Now it seems that I do not have table.html, chart.html and crosstab.html,  in the /adhoc folder. I wonder if those files are dynamically created or missing. Does someone have those files of jasper server 3.5.0 in /adhoc?

Answer (score 0):

The table, chart and crosstab were not generated by JSP because the DispatcherServlet could not figure out their path. I adjusted the path to start on the / in the JSP topicsExplorer.jsp and found various other places in JSPs where that path was not resolved correctly and then the user interface resolved fine.